# Invalid command 'SSLEngine' Centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I uninstalled Apache, and reinstalled it, and now when I try to start it I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 94 of /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13636697550.95452800_server.include:
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I did not try to enable SSL, or anything. I'm quite new to Linux, and Apache in general, so if somebody could help me with this, I would be infinitely grateful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is probably some forgotten configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d`. Find (`grep SSL /etc/httpd/{conf,conf.d} -r`) and destroy it or install ssl module for Apache:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

Comment: ** Faster:** yum -y install mod_ssl

Comment: This answer solve the issue for me as well

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had mod_ssl installed but it was not enabled. To do this I ran:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have already loaded mod_ssl in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```